# How to get values from within brackets?

Tags: perl, brackets

I have a value Mac(user, name)

How do i use perl reg expression to do a check on values inside the brackets.

Value: Mac(user,name)
Remove Mac.. and Do a check on (user,name) to check if it contains 'user'...?

Thanks for help!! :D

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.1;

my $input = q!Mac(user, name)!;

my ($user, $name) = $input =~ /^.*?\((.+?),\s*(.+?)\)$/;

say "user=$user , name=$name";
```

**output:**

```
user=user , name=name
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks all... i manage to use split to get data from my value

```
my @array = split (/[()]/, $input);
```

With this.. my value is store inside $array[1] :)

Answer (score 0):

The split solution is very fragile, if the string is badly formatted, it will return unexpected results.

If you want to be more strict, you can use this :

```
my $input = 'Mac(user, name)';

if (my ($user, $name) = $input =~ / Mac \( ([^,]+?) , ([^,]+?) \) /x) {
    say "user: $user, name: $name";
} else {
    die "input string '$input' is wrongly formatted";
}
```